# Playing an ogg format video using gstreamer in an embedded system

Tags: multimedia

I created a pipeline to play an ogg formatted video on an embedded system. I used the gst plugins like `libgstvorbis.so`, `libgsttheora.so`, and `libogg.so`, and copied them to the `/lib` folder on my embedded system. But when trying to play the video, 'm receiving warnings like

> (:25214): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin
>   '/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstogg.so': /lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstogg.so:
>   undefined symbol: gst_collect_pads2_start
>
> (:25214): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin
>   '/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvorbis.so': /lib/libm.so.6: version
>   `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by
>   /lib/gstreamer-0.10/libvorbis.so.0)
>
> (:25214): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin
>   '/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgsttheora.so':
>   /lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgsttheora.so: undefined symbol:
>   gst_element_class_add_static_pad_template

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you have incompatible versions of libraries installed on your system.

- `libgvorbis.so` was compiled against a different version of `libm`;: namely one that has a symbol `GLIBC_2.15`, and the `libm` you have installed lacks this symbol
- `libgstogg.so` and `libgsttheora.so` refer to gstreamer-functions not found in your `libstreamer-0.10.so`

this basically means that your build-environment is incompatible with your target platform.

"embedded" is a very wide area, and covers a multitude of architectures and operating systems.
the binaries you have been copying around have been created for the correct architecture, but it seems that there is a large version gap on the installed system.

hard to tell without more information.

depending on your system, you might have good luck by installing a full-fledged distro like *Debian* on it, which already comes with the required GStreamer plugins.